# getFilesDir() returning only a single file

Tags: android, android-file

I have an application with tens of files in it's directory. I have verified this by navigating to it through the file explorer in Android and indeed there are tens of files there.

Though when I run
`File dir = getActivity().getFilesDir();`

The file only contains one child, not the expected tens of children.

Comment: "The file explorer in Android" has no access to your app's `getFilesDir()`. Perhaps you mean `getExternalFilesDir()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare You are correct, getExternalFilesDir() works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A key indicator for this question was that the files were showing in the android 'file system viewer'. This viewer does not have access to the files accessed through getFilesDir(). The files shown in the viewer can be accessed through `File dir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir();`
See CommonWare's comment on the OP

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are checking `dir.listFiles()` instead of `dir` itself?

`dir` is the file that points to your directory while `dir.listFiles()` should return an array of files located in this directory.

If this doesn't solve your problem could you maybe provide a bit more information. Thank you

Comment: dir.getFiles() doesn't seem to be the correct syntax? It isn't working for me. I am using dir.listFiles() to get the list of files in the directory. But I have also inspected the dir variable through debugging and it only had one child.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed some things up. It should indeed be listFiles(). Did CommonsWare's comment solve your problem?

Comment: No problem, I also edited my answer for any other unlucky soul that gets stuck with android's filesystem